# Changing Java manifest.mf file and deployment to server

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, jar

I'm developing an application that should run on a server. The application uses some external jars.

I have build the application and run it on a local machine without a problem.

Now, I need to deploy it on the server. The server has some of the jars located.

What should I do to make my application work on the server, using the jars that are already there?

I don't have much experience with Java, but I understand that there is a manifest file which has a class-path field that points to all the jars needed. Should I change the manifest "manually", so that it points to the location of the jar on the server? What do you do in situations like this, what is the correct procedure?

Also, if I use one version of jar during development, and there is a bit older version of that jar on the server, what should I do to perform the deployment correctly?

And what is the procedure in case of using maven, should I copy the jars from where it locates them on the local drive to one directory, or is there a way for maven to do it itself?

I'm using NetBeans btw.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Re *"using the jars that are already there":*

See [Introduction to the Dependency Mechanism, Dependency Scope](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope): *"**provided** ... indicates you expect the JDK or a container to provide the dependency at runtime."*

Re *"there is a bit older version of that jar on the server":*

Update the library on the server or use the older when developing. I'd consider it a really bad idea to use different versions of a library for developing and runtime. This can lead to subtle errors that are hard to identify.

Re *"And what is the procedure in case of using maven":*

Does the introduction linked above help you in answering this as well?

Maven is supposed to work the same with any type of IDE.